# How to sample Logits and Probabilties from a transformer seq2seq model for reinforcement learning?

Tags: nlp, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

skipping the formalities:

I am trying to apply reinforcement learning to a transformer based seq2seq model (for abstractive summarization purposes) in Pytorch.

My current setup looks something like this:

1. I am getting a greedy distribution (summary) from the model by inferring one token at a time in a loop

   ```
   def get_greedy_distribution(model, batch):
       src, (shift_tgt, lbl_tgt), segs, clss, mask_src, mask_tgt, mask_cls = batch

       # the mock targets are just torch.zeros tensors to store inferred tokens
       mock_tgt = get_mock_tgt(shift_tgt)
       mock_return = get_mock_tgt(shift_tgt)

       max_length = shift_tgt.shape[1]

       with torch.no_grad():
           for i in range(0, max_length-1):
               prediction = model(src, mock_tgt, segs, clss, mask_src, mask_tgt, mask_cls)
               prediction = F.softmax(prediction, dim=2)
               val, ix = prediction.data.topk(1)
               mock_tgt[:, i+1] = ix.squeeze()[:, i].detach()
               mock_return[:, i] = ix.squeeze()[:, i].detach()

       return mock_return
   ```
2. I am getting a sample distribution, with probabilities, from the model in a similar way:

   ```
   def get_distribution(model, batch):
       src, (shift_tgt, lbl_tgt), segs, clss, mask_src, mask_tgt, mask_cls = batch
       mock_tgt = get_mock_tgt(shift_tgt)
       mock_return = get_mock_tgt(shift_tgt)

       max_length = shift_tgt.shape[1]

       log_probs = []

       for i in range(0, max_length-1):
           prediction = model(src, mock_tgt, segs, clss, mask_src, mask_tgt, mask_cls)
           prediction = F.softmax(prediction, dim=2)

           multi_dist = Categorical(prediction[:, i])
           x_t = multi_dist.sample()
           log_prob = multi_dist.log_prob(x_t)

           mock_tgt[:, i+1] = x_t
           mock_return[:, i] = x_t

           log_probs.append(log_prob)

       return mock_return, log_probs
   ```

However, I am a bit unsure if I am inferring the sample distribution correctly. This would work well in an RNN context where I can sample logits and probabilities during the typical RNN loop, but it feels slightly wrong when using a Transformer.

How would you suggest to approach the Transformer for a typical baseline-sampled reinforcement learning setup (I am guessing it is a policy gradient)? 
Pytorch code is preferred but if you have Tensorflow examples I am sure I can figure it out.